# Angular using a fragment and child in URL

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I am trying to use a router fragment as part of a username to allow users to copy a link to their "dashboard".  I also want to have some children of that dashboard which would be able to control the content shown on the page, but keep the same page wrapper.

I am trying to make a url like `site.com/u/ntgcleaner#1234/sets` and `site.com/u/ntgcleaner#1234/uniques`.

There's also a possibility of a url like `site.com/u/ntgcleaner/sets` and `site.com/u/ntgcleaner/uniques`.

`ntgcleaner#1234` and `ntgcleaner` are two different users.

My initial router setup is something like this:

```
 {
    path: 'u/:userId',
    component: DashboardComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    children: [
      { path: '', redirectTo: 'sets', pathMatch: 'full' },
      {
        path: 'sets',
        component: SetsComponent,
        pathMatch:'full'
      },
      {
        path: 'uniques',
        component: UniquesComponent,
        pathMatch:'full'
      }
    ]
  },
```

If a user went to `site.com/u/ntgcleaner`, it should default redirect to `site.com/u/ntgcleaner/sets`. Or, if a user goes to `site.com/u/ntgcleaner#1234`, it should redirect to `site.com/u/ntgcleaner#1234/sets`

When I do this setup above, if I go to `site.com/u/ntgcleaner#1234`, the redirect tries to take me to the sets page, but the url turns into `site.com/u/ntgcleaner/sets#1234`

If I go to `site.com/u/ntgcleaner#1234/sets` it will direct me to `site.com/u/ntgcleaner/sets#1234/sets`

I'm not sure how to get it to work the way I'd like.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Option 1 Don't use a "hashtag" in the user id this is being inferred as a separate strategy. Option 2 implement Angular's "UrlMatcher" to create a custom route matcher.

Comment: Thank you I will look into urlmatcher